# I want to travel in Uk with my spouse

Tags: uk, paperwork, france, spouses, brussels

I am interested about some informations.
We are a new couple and we want to travel in Uk for honeymoon from brussel by train. My wife is EU citizen. Can we travel in UK together with marriage certificate.

Please some informations.

Comment: And your citizenship is ...?

Comment: Also, when do you intend to do this? Before the end of the year the UK is still in the transition period and EU rules continue to apply, but Covid will probably prevent you from doing anything but stay in quarantine, and from next year whenever Covid restrictions are lifted, the UK will probably no longer abide by EU rules, and I'm not sure the rules for your specific case are known.

Comment: This page https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-from-1-january-2021 and this https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control may be of help. Remember to check that your health insurance cover is adequate.

Comment: I want to go next week...absolutely before 31 december

Comment: I dont have already eea permit i contacted my lawyer amd she says me the Permit will be available for 4 5 weeks

Comment: @Liku You can’t travel to England until at least 3 December because of the lockdown. And even if/when non-essential travel is allowed again in England, many areas may still be under restrictions, you would probably have to isolate for 14 days, and a lot of tourist attractions are likely to be closed or operating with very restricted entry. So TBH little point in a trip. See https://www.gov.uk/coronavirus for more information

Answer (score 9):

> We are a new couple and we want to travel in Uk for honeymoon from brussel by train.

> I want to go next week...absolutely before 31 december

Forget about it.  Due to the [COVID-19 pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic) you cannot possibly travel for honeymoon purposes from Brussel to the United Kingdom by train next week.  You can almost certainly not have a normal honeymoon before 31 December 2020.  From the [UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/coronavirus):

> you must not travel in the UK or overseas, unless for a specific reason, like education, work or a caring responsibility

You can certainly not have a honeymoon in England next week.

You can almost certainly not have a honeymoon in England in 2020.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to enter the UK without a visa, with proof of your marriage, but it is not certain.

First, if you are a citizen of a country whose citizens normally do not require a visa for a short visit to the UK, then you do not need a visa.

Second, if you have a residence card issued by Belgium (or any other EU or EEA country or Switzerland), and that card says that it is a "residence card of a family member of an EU citizen," then you can use that card instead of a visa when you are traveling with the EU family member.

Third, if you lack such a card, you are in general supposed to have an EEA family permit, which is essentially a visa.  It must be issued free of charge and on the basis of an accelerated and simplified application procedure.  To fly to the UK, the airline will require you to show the family permit before they will allow you to board the aircraft.

Fourth, if you lack the EEA family permit, you may be admitted under a provision in the Immigration (EEA) Regulations 2016 that allows you to "prove by other means" that you are entitled to the right of free movement.  (This provision gives effect to a corresponding provision in the free movement directive 2004/38/EC.)  This means that an immigration officer at the border should admit you under the circumstances you describe.  We have reports on this site (although not recent ones) of people doing this successfully.

Fifth, some advice: if I were in your shoes, I would therefore apply for an EEA family permit if time allows.  Having one gives you more certainty at the border.  You probably won't be turned back, but it's possible.  Why add uncertainty (and the attendant stress) to your trip?

Finally, the rules will change at 11 PM GMT on December 31, 2020 (midnight of 2020-12-31/2021-01-01 in Belgium and France), so if your anticipated visit is after that time, you should ignore this answer and apply for a normal visitor visa.

Comment: And of course there are Covid-related restrictions in force in both Belgium and the UK at the moment which I think won't allow OP to travel to the UK for a honeymoon at this time, and probably not before the end of transition period either.